# My php form generates errors on bluehost server

Tags: php, forms, bluehost

I have created a contact form for my website. When I press the send button the form goes to a thank you page as it should. When the thank you page displays the url changes and a folder /info/ is added.  see below:

http://www.projectrefresh.net/info/thankyou.html

After this happens all pages are broken as /info/ has been added and is not recognized.

Contact form code:

```
<form name="contact" method="POST" action="enquiryForm.php"> 
<p><b>Name</b><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name="Name" size=40>
</tr>
<tr>
<p><b>Your Email</b><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name="email" size=40>
</tr>
<tr>
<p><b>Company</b><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name="Company" size=40>
</tr>
<tr>
<p><b>Subject</b><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name="subject" size=40>
</tr>
<tr>
<p><b>Message</b><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="message"></textarea>
</tr>
<tr>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Send ">
</tr>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php

$to="info@projectrefresh.net"; // what email address do you wish the email to be sent to?

$subject="Enquiry from website"; // what subject do you want the email to have

$sendto="thankyou.html"; // where do you want the visitor to be sent to afterwards?

//

// This is an UNSUPPORTED web form to email PHP script for usage by DiYhost.co.uk customers

//

$message = "This message has been sent from ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."\n\n\n";

while(list($var, $val)=each($HTTP_POST_VARS)){        // Get all variables

$message .= "[".$var."]: ".$val."\n\n";                // build the message body           

}

$message .= "\n\nThe person's IP address who sent this email is: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

mail($to, $subject, $message,

    "From: webmaster@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."\r\n"

  ."Reply-To: webmaster@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."\r\n"

  ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

// see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

                    .dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

                    ."/".$sendto);

?>
```

Comment: The `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is obsolete, and should be replaced by `$_POST['key']`, without omitting input sanitizing.

Comment: What does your html form look like? Showing how you build an email is utterly pointless when you're talking about form problems.

Comment: Here is the form code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a very helpful "de-coding" site:  http://validator.w3.org/  - entering your page came up with = 52 Errors, 3 warning(s)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the links is that if they are like this...

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

They are relative to the **current** page. You could solve your issue by making them relative to the root of the website:

```
<a href="/index.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with your host provider's php environment.
Probably the dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns the unexpected result.

How about replacing the header redirect without the full path, just the page:

```
header("Location: $sendto");
```

If you want to see where the extra "info" dir comes from debug to output:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Replace header(... with the above 3 lines. You could copy the result here.